# theme.json to bootstrap variables

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to override bootstrap css variables with Wordpress theme.json generated variables. Is there a standard/best practices way to do this? I can't seem to find exactly what I want - which it to set bootstrap css varirables to wp variables...